# Showing Database call result in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

Short Question, Is it possible to make a database call in the first load of home page using Struts 2? I have this old project of mine, just a simple online shop(wasn't able to finish it though) and i recalled that i was having a hard time with my home page outputting products listed in the database since struts needed to trigger an action before doing anything. Can you like preload some actions before proceeding to the home JSP? I'm a beginner in struts and could just do simple redirect and other basic actions.

Comment: trigger the action on the page load..

Comment: i think i figured out what i really need. Have to make a ServletContextListener for it to initialize data while deploying the app

Comment: Action -> JSP. Not other way around.

Answer (score 0):

You have many ways to do it. But most easiest way is mapping a action with the home page URL. Action class should do whatever database loading or other logic and forward to the JSP page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the s:action tag in your home page. There are 2 different ways it could be approached.

1. the only thing in your home page is the `<s:action/>` tag and let it render the result of the action: executeResult="true" attribute.
2. specify the var="myaction" attribute and set executeResult="false".  You can then access everything from the action through the var name.  for example `<s:property value="%{myaction.myproperty}"/>`

The docs for the s:action tag can be found here: https://struts.apache.org/docs/action.html

Answer (score 0):

Use a list method with s:iterator on your home.jsp.